# NSURLConnection times out when doing PUT of binary

Tags: ios, nsurlconnection

I'm trying to use NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest: to send a binary file (an JPEG image) to a server.  The code I have is:

```
// url contains the URL of the remote server.
// fileURL contains the URL for the local file to be sent.

request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setCachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"PUT"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[request setValue:@"image/jpeg" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBodyStream:[NSInputStream inputStreamWithURL:fileURL]];

responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&requestError];

if (requestError != nil) {
    NSLog(@"%@", requestError);
    return NO;
}
```

This almost works. The remote server receives the request properly, and responds with an appropriate JSON object.  But sendSynchronousRequest: blocks until the timeout value, and then reports a timeout.

Elsewhere, I'm able to send and receive JSON objects properly using pretty much this same code pattern, so I'm baffled why this one would be timing out.

Comment: afaik synchronous stuff is meant to be blocking.

Comment: did you try increasing the timeout? Btw, does `fileURL` used in `setHTTPBodyStream` contain boundaries/content-types etc? It should be identical to when you use `setHTTPBody`. I would recommend using AFNetworking or such libraries for simplifying http requests.

Comment: You should implement it _asynchronously_ using a NSURLConnectionDelegate. You will have and must have better control about the connection. Explicitly setting the Content-Length header may also help, since otherwise NSURLConnection may send the data with chunked transfer encoding - which may have other issues.